# Building Mercurial 1.3.1 on Ubuntu Linux

Tags: linux, mercurial, build, makefile, build-error

I'm attempting to build mercurial 1.3.1. I've attempted this thus far on my Mac OS X machine and on a Linux Ubuntu virtual machine that I'm running.

I keep getting errors while running the make. I know there are binaries availble for both Linux and Mac, but I want to build my own copy. I've always skipped out on building and I want to learn how to do this.

But now, I need help. Here is the results from the entire build process from my Ubuntu Linux v9.04 machine... The error `error: Python.h: No such file or directory` towards the end. I've included all of the results in case this helps someone trouble shoot.

```
frank@ubuntu:~/Desktop/mercurial-1.3.1$ sudo make install
[sudo] password for frank: 
python setup.py  build
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.linux-i686-2.6
creating build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/mercurial
copying mercurial/dirstate.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/mercurial
copying mercurial/bundlerepo.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/mercurial
copying mercurial/subrepo.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/mercurial
copying mercurial/httprepo.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/mercurial
copying mercurial/__version__.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/mercurial
copying mercurial/changelog.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/mercurial
copying mercurial/repo.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/mercurial
copying mercurial/config.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/mercurial
copying mercurial/byterange.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/mercurial
copying mercurial/verify.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/mercurial
copying mercurial/encoding.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/mercurial
copying mercurial/keepalive.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/mercurial
copying mercurial/sshserver.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/mercurial
copying mercurial/fancyopts.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/mercurial
copying mercurial/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/mercurial
copying mercurial/merge.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/mercurial
copying mercurial/i18n.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/mercurial
copying mercurial/archival.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/mercurial
copying mercurial/match.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/mercurial
copying mercurial/mail.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/mercurial
copying mercurial/help.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/mercurial
copying mercurial/win32.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/mercurial
copying mercurial/posix.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/mercurial
copying mercurial/repair.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/mercurial
copying mercurial/dispatch.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/mercurial
copying mercurial/error.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/mercurial
copying mercurial/templatefilters.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/mercurial
copying mercurial/localrepo.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/mercurial
copying mercurial/sshrepo.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/mercurial
copying mercurial/node.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/mercurial
copying mercurial/templater.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/mercurial
copying mercurial/streamclone.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/mercurial
copying mercurial/context.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/mercurial
copying mercurial/strutil.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/mercurial
copying mercurial/ignore.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/mercurial
copying mercurial/hook.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/mercurial
copying mercurial/mdiff.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/mercurial
copying mercurial/ui.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/mercurial
copying mercurial/lsprofcalltree.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/mercurial
copying mercurial/transaction.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/mercurial
copying mercurial/commands.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/mercurial
copying mercurial/windows.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/mercurial
copying mercurial/revlog.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/mercurial
copying mercurial/store.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/mercurial
copying mercurial/lock.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/mercurial
copying mercurial/changegroup.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/mercurial
copying mercurial/lsprof.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/mercurial
copying mercurial/manifest.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/mercurial
copying mercurial/url.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/mercurial
copying mercurial/util.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/mercurial
copying mercurial/demandimport.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/mercurial
copying mercurial/graphmod.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/mercurial
copying mercurial/statichttprepo.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/mercurial
copying mercurial/cmdutil.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/mercurial
copying mercurial/extensions.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/mercurial
copying mercurial/filemerge.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/mercurial
copying mercurial/hg.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/mercurial
copying mercurial/filelog.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/mercurial
copying mercurial/copies.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/mercurial
copying mercurial/hbisect.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/mercurial
copying mercurial/patch.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/mercurial
copying mercurial/ancestor.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/mercurial
copying mercurial/simplemerge.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/mercurial
creating build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/mercurial/hgweb
copying mercurial/hgweb/webutil.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/mercurial/hgweb
copying mercurial/hgweb/request.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/mercurial/hgweb
copying mercurial/hgweb/wsgicgi.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/mercurial/hgweb
copying mercurial/hgweb/protocol.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/mercurial/hgweb
copying mercurial/hgweb/server.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/mercurial/hgweb
copying mercurial/hgweb/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/mercurial/hgweb
copying mercurial/hgweb/common.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/mercurial/hgweb
copying mercurial/hgweb/hgwebdir_mod.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/mercurial/hgweb
copying mercurial/hgweb/webcommands.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/mercurial/hgweb
copying mercurial/hgweb/hgweb_mod.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/mercurial/hgweb
creating build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/hgext
copying hgext/pager.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/hgext
copying hgext/purge.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/hgext
copying hgext/graphlog.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/hgext
copying hgext/win32text.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/hgext
copying hgext/gpg.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/hgext
copying hgext/hgk.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/hgext
copying hgext/color.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/hgext
copying hgext/bugzilla.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/hgext
copying hgext/bookmarks.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/hgext
copying hgext/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/hgext
copying hgext/notify.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/hgext
copying hgext/record.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/hgext
copying hgext/interhg.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/hgext
copying hgext/rebase.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/hgext
copying hgext/churn.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/hgext
copying hgext/keyword.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/hgext
copying hgext/mq.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/hgext
copying hgext/transplant.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/hgext
copying hgext/acl.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/hgext
copying hgext/children.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/hgext
copying hgext/fetch.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/hgext
copying hgext/extdiff.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/hgext
copying hgext/win32mbcs.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/hgext
copying hgext/share.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/hgext
copying hgext/parentrevspec.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/hgext
copying hgext/hgcia.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/hgext
copying hgext/patchbomb.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/hgext
creating build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/hgext/convert
copying hgext/convert/bzr.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/hgext/convert
copying hgext/convert/convcmd.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/hgext/convert
copying hgext/convert/gnuarch.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/hgext/convert
copying hgext/convert/cvsps.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/hgext/convert
copying hgext/convert/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/hgext/convert
copying hgext/convert/git.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/hgext/convert
copying hgext/convert/p4.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/hgext/convert
copying hgext/convert/subversion.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/hgext/convert
copying hgext/convert/transport.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/hgext/convert
copying hgext/convert/common.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/hgext/convert
copying hgext/convert/hg.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/hgext/convert
copying hgext/convert/monotone.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/hgext/convert
copying hgext/convert/cvs.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/hgext/convert
copying hgext/convert/filemap.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/hgext/convert
copying hgext/convert/darcs.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/hgext/convert
creating build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/hgext/highlight
copying hgext/highlight/highlight.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/hgext/highlight
copying hgext/highlight/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/hgext/highlight
creating build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/hgext/zeroconf
copying hgext/zeroconf/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/hgext/zeroconf
copying hgext/zeroconf/Zeroconf.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/hgext/zeroconf
creating build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/hgext/inotify
copying hgext/inotify/server.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/hgext/inotify
copying hgext/inotify/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/hgext/inotify
copying hgext/inotify/common.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/hgext/inotify
copying hgext/inotify/client.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/hgext/inotify
creating build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/hgext/inotify/linux
copying hgext/inotify/linux/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/hgext/inotify/linux
copying hgext/inotify/linux/watcher.py -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.6/hgext/inotify/linux
running build_ext
building 'mercurial.base85' extension
creating build/temp.linux-i686-2.6
creating build/temp.linux-i686-2.6/mercurial
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.6 -c mercurial/base85.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.6/mercurial/base85.o
mercurial/base85.c:12:20: error: Python.h: No such file or directory
mercurial/base85.c: In function ‘b85prep’:
mercurial/base85.c:23: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘memset’
mercurial/base85.c:23: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘memset’
mercurial/base85.c: At top level:
mercurial/base85.c:28: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
mercurial/base85.c:76: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘*’ token
mercurial/base85.c:141: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘methods’
mercurial/base85.c:150: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘initbase85’
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
make: *** [build] Error 1
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Make sure you have the python-dev package installed:

```
apt-get install python-dev
```

Comment: I've checked on Python - I have Python 2.6.2

Comment: You need both the python and the python-dev packages installed.  Run the command above and then run the Mercurial install again...

Comment: Thank you. I didn't realize there was a difference between "Python" and Python-dev.

Answer (score 2):

I know you want to build from source, but for OS X (and elsewhere) you could simply use Python's easy_install (get it with [Setuptools](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools)):

```
sudo easy_install mercurial
```

since Mercurial is written in Python. This finds the latest version (1.3.1 at time of writing) and (I don't use Macports or Fink) installs it nicely with no fuss at:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/
```

I run Python 2.6 (on Mac OS 10.4.11) so this also gets around the [Mercurial OS X installer package](http://mercurial.berkwood.com/) (only at 1.2.1 as of July 25 2009) complaint about needing Python 2.5.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=497109):

> I just hadn't realized that by default only part of Python is installed, and I needed to install the python-dev package which includes all the header files.

That's for Linux.  I'm pretty sure on OS X the Python.h will only be installed if you've installed the Developer Tools.  Did you install them?

Comment: Yes, this helped but the command was the answer... So I have to give it to Jon...

Comment: Yes, I have the developer tools for Mac OS. Though, this particular post is for my Ubuntu setup.

Comment: Ah, you didn't mention whether the build on OS X succeeded or not.  From the original question it sounded like it did not.